# I cant get my python discord bot polling command to send. All the other response commands work, so im not sure why the poll wont send

Tags: python, discord.py, ctx

Here is my code

```py
@bot.command("poll")
async def poll(ctx, *args):
    # poll command:
    # !poll event_name event_date
    event_name = args[0]
    event_date = args[1]
    # retrieving the 'events' channel
    # sending the poll
    message = await ctx.send(f"@everyone Will you come to the **{event_name}** event the **{event_date}**?")
    # adding reactions to the poll
    await message.add_reaction('U00002705')
    await message.add_reaction('U0000274C')
```

I keep getting an error code called

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

and i dont know how to get my code to work

Ive been following a tutorial and for some reason my code wont work with it. i keep getting the `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: tuple index out of range` error message

Comment: _Ive been following a tutorial_ Can you give a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Are you sure you're invoking it with two arguments?

Comment: I'm asking because I'm genuinely curious. Is there a reason to use *args here instead of creating two parameters for the function. I feel like there will always only be two arguments right?

Answer (score 0):

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1019539306777415712/1039502797420376074/25f07d49ecf5de59.png
u need to give arg and it work, but u will get unkonwn emoji error , beacuse u don't use \ in unicode

```
    await message.add_reaction('U00002705')
```

use ('\U00002705')